# In Python - Trying to aggregate the same names in the B column and sum their totals from each total in Column C

Tags: python

In Python - Trying to aggregate the same names in the  B column and sum their totals from each total in Column C.

For example.

```
Bob   4
Bob   1
Bob   2
Tyler  3
Sam    4
```

into:

```
Bob 7
Tyler 3
Sam 4
```

Comment: `df.groupby('B').C.sum()`? or `df.groupby('B',as_index=False).C.sum()`-->`B` is not index in this case.

Comment: if this is python and not some db integrations, please post data structure

Comment: I would also like to add a count function after. So for every model name under each different custodian. There is a count that says there this many models in that name under each different Custodian name. (for example. there are 529 plans under different custodian names as we.. That needs to be aggregated as well. One line for each model name and custodian that are the same. If we can add this column to the right of current value and name it # of Accounts

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPS, it means you are shouting.

Comment: I am Italian... sorry lol